# Saving Multiple Null With Spatie Translatable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-translatable

I'm having problem when saving multiple null value for translatable column

It's with spatie translatable packages, so i define `public $translatable = ['description'];` and saving post like this `$category->setTranslations('description', ['en' => null, 'fr' => null]);` but somehow saved like `{"fr":null}` only

I'm expected `{"en":null,"id":null}` or `null` or `{}`. Looks wrong for me when i post `['en' => null, 'fr' => null]` but saved only `{"fr":null}`. I think it's because both value is null so `en` replaced with `fr` but i'm not sure